# Loan-word for a relaxed cultural attitude towards opening and closing times

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, cultural-phrases

"No customers, so I closed early. Xxxxx, right?"

For example, a recent visitor to Hawaii described stores closing hours before the posted times on occasional days "just because"

Santa Cruz CA restaurants would bemoan the difficulty of staff attendence when the surf was up

What is a good term for the cultural-wide, relative absence of punctuality?

Comment: Can you translate “cultural-wide” into English please.

Comment: I am not sure there is a term for “a relaxed approach to punctuality” but it certainly is an issue.

Comment: Must this be a loan word from another language? Also, must this be a single word where maybe two words or a phrase might work?

Comment: Plenty places in the UK do this.

Comment: I remember a 2-centre package holiday my wife and I went on based in the Italian Lakes and Alto Adige. The flight had been delayed for hours, but some official on the coach ferrying us from Bergamo airport to Lazise, after apologising, said "Don't worry – the bars are open from 7 am to 2 am." Quick as a flash, someone at the back of the coach retorted "Any after-hours?"

Comment: I'd imagine you'd find something in this TED talk from Brittney Cooper https://www.ted.com/talks/brittney_cooper_the_racial_politics_of_time/transcript?c=55740

Answer (score 1):

Although it's a phrase and it doesn't contain a loan word, there is a bit of support in Google Books for

**lax business hours**

> He used to wander around Wall Street at 7 o'clock in the morning and
> upbraid the merchants in their offices for the **lax business hours**
> of this generation. [George Putnam; *Salem Vessels and Their Voyages,
> Vol. 3*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Salem_Vessels_and_Their_Voyages/EaQHAQAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22lax%20business%20hours%22&pg=PA95&printsec=frontcover) (1925)

> Argentina is relatively easy to get around but expect certain
> inconveniences at times, such as late buses or **lax business hours**
> (this varies region to region and with the size of the city or town).
> [Erin McCloskey; *Argentina: The Bradt Travel Guide*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Argentina/LMlE62g1hWAC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22lax%20business%20hours%22&pg=PA81&printsec=frontcover) (2011)

> The A B C's of the Unsuccessful Telephone Man
>
> A Keeping **lax business hours.**
> B Failure to maintain emergency  location information when absent.
> С Careless use of teams and other
> vehicles ...  [*Michigan State Gazette*, Vols. 5-6](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Michigan_State_Gazette/FwyL6Bk1jt4C?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22keeping%20lax%22) (1909)

Comment: "irregular hours" is another phrase for anything that doesn't keep to a regular, unchanging schedule. But it's not directed at any ethnicity/race/nationality/language, so it may not be what the OP requires.